# Run python code from a certain point

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going some data analysis with python, and it involves reading data at the beginning of the script. I am currently debugging it, and it is cumbersome to wait for the data file to read each time. Is there any way that I can do something similar to a breakpoint which python will not need to read the data each time? It would just begin with the code below reading the data.

Comment: ipython is probably worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds from your question like you have some lines at the beginning of a script which you do not want to process each time you run the script. That particular scenario is not really something that makes a lot of sense from a scripting point of view. Scripts are read from the top down unless you call a function or something. With that said, here is what I'm gathering you want your workflow to be like:

1. Do some time consuming data loading (once)
2. Try out code variations until one works
3. Be able to run the entire thing when you're done

If that's accurate, I suggest 3 options:

1. If you don't need the data that's loaded from step 1 in the specific code you're testing, just comment out the time consuming portion until you're done with the new code
2. If you do need the data, but not ALL of the data to test your new code, create a variable that looks like a small subset of the actual data returned, comment out the time consuming portion, then switch it back when complete. Something like this:

   ```
   # data_result = time_consuming_file_parser()
   data_result = [row1, row2, row3]

   # new code using data_result
   ```
3. Finally, if you absolutely need the full data set but don't want to wait for it to load every time before you make changes, try looking into `pdb` or Python DeBugger. This will let you put a breakpoint after your data load and then play around in the python shell until you are satisfied with your result.

   ```
   import pdb
   pdb.set_trace()
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel kinda dumb right now to have not looked at a subset of my data. In the future, I'll look into pdb if necessary.